# Core Data custom struct array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I created a custom struct named `Answer`:

```
struct Answer {
    var isCorrect : Int
    var time : Double
    
}
```

and I made a class which contains an array of Answers

```
class TestResult {
    var name : String
    var answers : [Answer]
    var date : Date
    init(name: String, answers: [Answer],date: Date) {
        self.name = name; self.answers = answers; self.date = date;
    }
}
```

And I want to save `TestResult` instances to CoreData, I created an Entity called `TestResultCoreData` and added a Date and a String attribute to store name and date.

How should I save the `Answer` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your core data model, create an entity called `Answer` and make the relationship a 1-to-many between the two entities `TestResult` and `Answer`.

Or declare the answers attribute as `Transformable` data type in your data model.

[image: Core data model]

Comment: I tried using a transformable attribute but I got an thread 1 signal SIGABRT error when trying to save. I dont how to work with relationships, I created a one to many relationship but I dont know what it means or how to use it. Could you please explain in details?

Comment: isn't transformable the type? also I researched about relationships and im trying to use them.